AWS Certificate Manager Verification
So I'm requesting an SSL certificate for my domain. I'm trying to request it for 2 FQDN,
EX:
"
domain.com
*.domain.com
"
When I try to validate this, I get 2 CNAME records to add to my DNS, but both of the CNAME names are the same and I can't add duplicate CNAMEs to godaddy. Has anyone had this issue? I would still like to use the * wildcard, but maybe I'm missing something.
I Tried adding two dns records, but they were duplicate names.

Are you sure both CNAME are the same? Because I've been managing multiple ACM certificates and I've never encountered a duplicate CNAME for certificate with multiple domains. Can you add a redacted screenshot of the certificate with the CNAMEs?

That's normal. You just need to create the one record.

Is one CNAME an A record (IPv4) and one a AAAA record (IPv6)?
